# How can I set up this input regex box to require a time?

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation, time

I have been creating a spreadsheet of inputs to allow insertion of times for when people will begin/end working, and so far I've gotten all submitting of everything working in PHP and all displays work with HTML/CSS, but I'm having difficulties setting up my Regex in JavaScript.

The format for the time input is:
`0-12` (Number, Indicate Starting Hour)
`:` (Colon, Split hour and minutes)
`0-59` (Number, For Minutes)
`A/P` (A or P, indicated AM or PM)
`-` (Hyphen, Split start and end times)
`0-12` (Number, Indicate Starting Hour)
`:` (Colon, Split hour and minutes)
`0-59` (Number, For Minutes)
`A/P` (A or P, indicated AM or PM)

The Regex that I was using while creating the other scripts is `/^(([[0-9:\]{1,5}\])+([ap])+(\-[[0-9:\]{1,5}\])+([ap]))/i` , which was working great until I realized that I needed to add a `$` to the end to set a limit to the length, and then it stopped working.

`/^(([[0-9:\]{1,5}\])+([ap])+(\-[[0-9:\]{1,5}\])+([ap]))$/i` accepts responses like `4a-5`, `4:30a-5`, `4:a-5`, and `4-5`. Once you add `:30` or `p` onto the end of the string it is no longer valid.

Could somebody help me construct a valid time Regex?

Thanks,

**Edit:** The input field is a "text" option.
I'm trying to get it to require at least `#a-#p`, and accept `:##` as well. (`#:##a-#:##p`)

Comment: A nice tool to fiddle http://regex101.com.

Comment: Is using the HTML `input` of type `time` an option?

Comment: Your pattern is full of mistakes, could you post several example strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern should do the job:

```
/^(?:1[0-2]?|[0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?[AP]-(?:1[0-2]?|[0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?[AP]$/i
```

Comment: That works exceptionally well, but how can I make the minutes time optional? To have 4a-5:30p without having to put 4:00a-5:30p

Comment: @TheElm: minutes are already optional in this pattern, since I have putted them in an optional non capturing group: `(?::[0-5][0-9])?`

Comment: @TheElm You can also use `<input type='time' />`

Comment: @hjpotter92 I'm putting together a spreadsheet of time (like when a person will work during a week) and need a quick way to type in two differences of time.